# PyQGIS 3 Disable save project in print layout and report manager (layout menus and gui buttons)

Tags: print-composer, pyqgis-3, reports, save, layout-manager

I would like to know how I can disable the 'save project' option in the QGIS print layout and report manager layout menus. I would also like to disable the save button on both gui's in PyQGIS 3.

[image: Save Project from print layout]
[image: Save project from the report manager]
[image: Save project button on gui]

For example:
The following code snippets can disable elements of the project menu of the QGIS interface, I need to do the same for the print layout and report manager sub-gui's:

```
iface.actionCreatePrintLayout().setEnabled(False)
iface.actionShowLayoutManager().setEnabled(False)
```

Yields:

[image: New print layout and layout manager disabled]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to disable the `Save Project` button, just specify the name of the layout or report:

```
layouts = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('reportOrLayoutName')
designer = iface.openLayoutDesigner(layouts)
layoutToolbar = designer.layoutToolbar()
for x in layoutToolbar.actions():
    if x.objectName() == 'mActionSaveProject':
        x.setEnabled(False)
```